# How to toggle visibility of span on depend on content of tbody

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I am using a table to populate data in tbody, also i am showing a span. 
The data is coming dynamically using Javascript. The dependency is something like this:

**if tbody empty : display SPAN**

**if tbody has data : hide SPAN**

// HTML code

```
<table id="incidents">
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
<br />
<button onclick="func()">Check table</button>
<br />

<span class="abc">Drop your files here to upload</span>
```

// Jquery code

```
function func() {
var tbody = $("#incidents tbody");

if (tbody.children().length != 0) {
      $('.abc').css('display','none');
    }
}
```

Comment: you want this to happen on a button click or on page load ?

Comment: I want this random, instead of on button click. something like onchange function

Answer (score 1):

Use [trim](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) as additional check

```
function func() {
  var contentLen = $.trim($("#incidents tbody").children()).length;

  if (contentLen == 0) {
   $('.abc').css('display','none');
  } else {
   $('.abc').css('display','block');
  }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if($("#incidents tbody").children().length > 0)
{
  $('.abc').css('display','none');
} 
else 
{
  $('.abc').css('display','block');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function func() {
  var tbody = $("#incidents tbody");

  if (tbody.children().length == 0) {
    $('.abc').removeClass('hide');
  }
}
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="incidents">
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br />
<button onclick="func()">Check table</button>
<br />

<span class="abc hide">Drop your files here to upload</span>
```

```js
function func() {
  var tbody = $("#incidents tbody");

  if (tbody.children().length == 0) {
    $('.abc').removeClass('hide');
  }
}
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="incidents">
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>asd</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br />
<button onclick="func()">Check table</button>
<br />

<span class="abc hide">Drop your files here to upload</span>
```

1. check if tbody children length is == 0
2. better to just add/remove class than directly putting css using jquery/js